# Override two methods at once

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, standards-compliance

The code below surprisingly compiles in VS 2012.

Method C::f() overrides methods in both base classes.

Is this standard behavior? I looked into C++11 standard, and didn't find any explicit mentioning of such situation.

```
class A { virtual void f() = 0; };

class B { virtual void f() = 0; };

class C : public A, public B { 
  virtual void f() override { } 
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The standard says, in C++11 10.3/2

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member function `vf` with the same name [etc.] as `Base::vf` is declared, then [...] it *overrides* `Base::vf`.

There are no special cases for multiple base classes, so a function declared in the derived class will override a suitable function in all base classes.

Comment: Yeah, I read the same section in the standard, and it didn't say directly 'in all base classes', but now you assured me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Herb Sutter explains how to deal with this [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/039.htm).

According to the article:

```
class B1 {
  public:
    virtual int ReadBuf( const char* );
    // ...
};

class B2 {
  public:
    virtual int ReadBuf( const char* );
    // ...
};

class D : public B1, public B2 {
  public:
    int ReadBuf( const char* ); // overrides both B1::ReadBuf and B2::ReadBuf
};
```

> This overrides BOTH functions with the same implementation